How to correctly change the command interface of the panda robot arm from 'position' to 'velocity' in the Moveit2 website tutorial
I followed the official Moveit2 website to create the panda robot arm and successfully ran demo.launch.py:
MoveIt Setup Assistant — MoveIt Documentation: Rolling documentation
Next I want to know how to change the command interface from 'position' to 'velocity'.
I changed two files:

ros2_controllers.yaml
panda.ros2_control.xacro

When I colcon build and ros2 launch panda_moveit_config demo.launch.py, the RViz and console look normal, and it "Plan" successfully. But when I finished planning and clicked the "Execute" button, rviz did not respond, and the console output looks successful. I wonder why rviz did not act.
Is there anything missing from my changes? Or what is the right change?
Here is the console output, along with the two files I changed.
console output:
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713256529.569964067] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256529.570737967] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256529.570926767] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713256529.571154567] [move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256529.579226867] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256529.579303767] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256529.579782367] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'robot_arm' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256529.634432567] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Motion plan was computed successfully.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713256529.635581867] [move_group_interface]: Planning request complete!
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713256529.635675367] [move_group_interface]: time taken to generate plan: 0.0163399 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.657329254] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Received goal request
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.657736354] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution request received
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.657824254] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.657872854] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.658506454] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713256535.658094154] [move_group_interface]: Execute request accepted
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.660050654] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Starting trajectory execution ...
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.660163154] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.660240354] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.660452454] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: sending trajectory to robot_arm_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1713256535.660962554] [robot_arm_controller]: Received new action goal
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1713256535.661051554] [robot_arm_controller]: Accepted new action goal
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.661379754] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: robot_arm_controller started execution
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256535.661414754] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal request accepted!
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1713256545.758803767] [robot_arm_controller]: Goal reached, success!
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256545.761655467] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Controller 'robot_arm_controller' successfully finished
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256545.789580068] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status SUCCEEDED ...
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1713256545.789703768] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution completed: SUCCEEDED
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713256545.790211768] [move_group_interface]: Execute request success!

I changed the following two files, (changes are noted in the comments):

ros2_controllers.yaml:

# This config file is used by ros2_control
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz

    robot_arm_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController


    robot_hand_controller:
      type: position_controllers/GripperActionController


    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

robot_arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - panda_joint1
      - panda_joint2
      - panda_joint3
      - panda_joint4
      - panda_joint5
      - panda_joint6
      - panda_joint7
    command_interfaces:
      # - position
      # changed: 
      - velocity
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
robot_hand_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joint: panda_finger_joint1


panda.ros2_control.xacro

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:macro name="panda_ros2_control" params="name initial_positions_file">
    <xacro:property name="initial_positions" value="${load_yaml(initial_positions_file)['initial_positions']}"/>
<ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
      <hardware>
        <!-- By default, set up controllers for simulation. This won't work on real hardware -->
        <plugin>mock_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
      </hardware>
      <joint name="panda_joint1">
        <!-- changed -->
        <command_interface name="velocity"/> <!-- position -->
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint1']}</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="panda_joint2">
    <!-- changed -->
    <command_interface name="velocity"/> <!-- position -->
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint2']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="panda_joint3">
        <!-- changed -->
        <command_interface name="velocity"/> <!-- position -->
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint3']}</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="panda_joint4">
    <!-- changed -->
    <command_interface name="velocity"/> <!-- position -->
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint4']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="panda_joint5">
        <!-- changed -->
        <command_interface name="velocity"/> <!-- position -->
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint5']}</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="panda_joint6">
    <!-- changed -->
    <command_interface name="velocity"/> <!-- position -->
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint6']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="panda_joint7">
        <!-- changed -->
        <command_interface name="velocity"/> <!-- position -->
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint7']}</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="panda_finger_joint1">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_finger_joint1']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
    </ros2_control>
  </xacro:macro>
</robot>


Here is the file moveit_controllers.yaml, and I didn't change it
moveit_controllers.yaml
# MoveIt uses this configuration for controller management

moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager

moveit_simple_controller_manager:
  controller_names:
    - robot_arm_controller
    - robot_hand_controller

  robot_arm_controller:
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
    # action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    # default: true
  robot_hand_controller:
    type: GripperCommand
    joints:
      - finger_joint_1
    action_ns: gripper_cmd
    default: true

RQT_GRAPH:


I think I got the crux. Maybe the the mock hardware(mock_components/GenericSystem) provided by ros2 control does not support the "velocity" command interface.
My approach to finding the problem was to create a custom hardware component.
The custom hardware component accepts the value from the 'velocity' command interfaces and writes directly to the 'velocity' state interfaces. And make position state follow position += velocity * period
When I changed the hardware component to the custom component, it worked.
See this link for more information on "mock_components/GenericSystem". I asked new questions and got answers:
Does the mock hardware component "mock_components/GenericSystem" provided by ros2 control support the 'velocity' command interface? - Robotics Stack Exchange

When you used the position as the command interface, did the robot in RViz move?
Print config file moveit_controllers.yaml from moveit config package if possible. Also, It would be good to see the node graph in RQT.
add
robot_arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    interface_name: velocity

to ros2_control.yaml
...only assuming from demo code
https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/example_3/bringup/config/rrbot_multi_interface_forward_controllers.yaml

Welcome to Robotics, Jakub Ivan and @Michael. On stack exchange, comments are not intended for extended discussions, they are for helping to improve questions and answers. Comments are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. They should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to tidy up a post. For extended discussion on a question or answer, please use [chat] when you have chat privileges.

Look at the second code section, where the interface name configuration in the "ros2_controllers.yaml" file uses the "command_interfaces" field. You can refer to this link: Details about parameters — ROS2_Control: Rolling Apr 2024 documentation
